# Compare the values of index with column names ; Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi I have two Dataframe as given below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(({"Column":{"0":"A","1":"B","2":"C","3":"A"},"Column2":{"0":"T1","1":"T2","2":"T1","3":"T1"}}))
```

[image: df1]

Then I created another dataframe using below statement

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(df1.shape[0],df1.shape[0])), columns=df1['Column'].values, index=df1['Column'].values)
```

[image: df2]

now i need to update df2 as if index is equals to column then assign value 1 if index is not equal to column then check in df1 if for that index and column value column2 value matches then assign value 2 else assign 3

Expected result:

[image: result]

Can we achieve it without using for loops ?

Note : Shape and values of df1 can be different every time,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
# STEP 1
df1 = df1.set_index(df1['Column'] + '_' + df1.groupby('Column').cumcount().astype(str))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros(shape=(df1.shape[0],df1.shape[0])), columns=df1.index, index=df1.index)

# STEP 2
df2 = df2.reset_index().melt('index', var_name='column')

# STEP 3:
m1 =  df2['index'].str.replace(r'(_\d+)$', '').eq(df2['column'].str.replace(r'(_\d+)$', ''))

# STEP 4
m2 = df1.lookup(df2['index'], ['Column2']*df2.shape[0]) == df1.lookup(df2['column'], ['Column2'] * df2.shape[0])

# STEP 5
df2['value'] = np.select([m1, m2], [1, 2], 3)

# STEP 6:
df2 = df2.pivot('index', 'column', 'value').rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)

# STEP 7: RESULT
df2 = df2.reindex(index=df1.index, columns=df1.index)
df2.index = df2.index.str.replace(r'(_\d+)$', '')
df2.columns = df2.columns.str.replace(r'(_\d+)$', '')
```

---

STEPS:

STEP 1: As the original dataframe contain duplicate values, we can use use `df.groupby` on `Column` and use `cumcount` and concatenate it with `df['Column']` to create a unique index in `df1`. Then we can initialise the new dataframe `df2` from the dataframe `df1`.

```
# STEP 1
# print(df2)
     A_0  B_0  C_0  A_1
A_0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
B_0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
C_0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
A_1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

STEP 2: Use [`DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to unpivot the dataframe.

```
# STEP 2
# print(df2)
   index column  value
0    A_0    A_0    0.0
1    B_0    A_0    0.0
2    C_0    A_0    0.0
3    A_1    A_0    0.0
4    A_0    B_0    0.0
5    B_0    B_0    0.0
6    C_0    B_0    0.0
7    A_1    B_0    0.0
8    A_0    C_0    0.0
9    B_0    C_0    0.0
10   C_0    C_0    0.0
11   A_1    C_0    0.0
12   A_0    A_1    0.0
13   B_0    A_1    0.0
14   C_0    A_1    0.0
15   A_1    A_1    0.0
```

STEP 3: Using [`Series.equals`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.equals.html) create a boolean mask `m1`, which correspond to condition where `index` in `df2` equals to `column` in `df2`.

```
# STEP 3
# print(m1)
[True, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, False, False, True, False, True, False, False, True]
```

STEP 4: Use [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) to create a boolean mask `m2` which corresponds to the condition where the values corresponding to `index` and `column` of `df2` in `df1['Column2']`  matches.

```
# STEP 4
# print(m2)
[True, False, True, True, False, True, False, False, True, False, True, True, True, False, True, True]
```

STEP 5: Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) to choose elements from `[1, 2]` based on conditions from `[m1, m2]` otherwise choose the default value `3`.

```
# STEP 5
# print(df2)
   index column  value
0    A_0    A_0      1
1    B_0    A_0      3
2    C_0    A_0      2
3    A_1    A_0      1
4    A_0    B_0      3
5    B_0    B_0      1
6    C_0    B_0      3
7    A_1    B_0      3
8    A_0    C_0      2
9    B_0    C_0      3
10   C_0    C_0      1
11   A_1    C_0      2
12   A_0    A_1      1
13   B_0    A_1      3
14   C_0    A_1      2
15   A_1    A_1      1
```

STEP 6: Use [`DataFrame.pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) to reshape dataframe based on `index` and `column` values.

```
# STEP 6:
# print(df2)
     A_0  A_1  B_0  C_0
A_0    1    1    3    2
A_1    1    1    3    2
B_0    3    3    1    3
C_0    2    2    3    1
```

STEP 7: Use [`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) to reindex(rearrange) the index and columns of `df2` according the index of `df1`. Then using [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html), remove the counter portion in the index and columns which has been added in STEP 1.

```
# STEP 7: RESULT
# print(df2)
   A  B  C  A
A  1  3  2  1
B  3  1  3  3
C  2  3  1  2
A  1  3  2  1
```

Comment: This is working as expected but in my case df1 "Column" can contain duplicate values and i want to include all those duplicates as well

Comment: @SakshiGupta Can you update the question with an example where df1 column contains duplicate values and also provide an expected output for such case.

Comment: Done @shubhamSharma

Comment: @SakshiGupta Well its going to be complicated scenario with duplicates, I will try to come up with the possible solution.

Comment: @SakshiGupta In your expected output i guess the second row should be `3, 1, 3, 3`

Comment: Yes Correct @shubhamsharma